# ByteArray intent extra is null after using putExtra inside apply

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-jetpack-compose

I'm receiving an encoded base64 ByteArray from our backend that contains some excel data. I need to create an excel file in the Downloads directory and write the decoded content inside it. I've managed to create the file, decode the array and make sure that the decodedByteArray is not null when it's passed through the callback back to the composable screen. However,
even though the `Log.d("TEST_EW","byte array = ${byteArray.contentToString()}")` line inside `apply{..}` (bottom of the composable file) is run and prints the data successfully, after the intent is constructed, the line below it that attempts to retrieve the ByteArrayExtra fails because the extra's value is null. I can't understand where things go wrong in my code. I want to store it in the intent because as you can see later, I want to retrieve the content in order to write the data to the file inside of the launcher callback.

viewModel:

```
class MainNavControllerViewModel(private val statementControllerUseCase: StatementControllerUseCase) :
    ViewModel() {

    fun exportTransactionsInExcel(context: Context, onSuccessCallback: (String,ByteArray) -> Unit) {
        val accountId =
            App.instance.appContext.getPreferenceThroughKeystore(PreferenceKeys.ACCOUNT_ID.key)
        val language = App.instance.preferences.getString(PreferenceKeys.LANGUAGE_CODE.key, "el")
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            when (val response = statementControllerUseCase.getTransactionsInExcel(
                "10395098", //TODO temporary accountid with data
                language.toString()
            )) {
                is ResponseResult.Success -> {
                    if (response.data != null) {
                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                            val currentTime: Date = Calendar.getInstance().time
                            val formattedDate = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
                            val fileName = "Transactions-${formattedDate.format(currentTime)}.xlsx"
                            val decodedByteArray = Base64.decode(response.data, Base64.DEFAULT)
                            Log.d("TEST_EW","decoded bytearray = ${Arrays.toString(decodedByteArray)}")
                            onSuccessCallback(fileName,decodedByteArray)
                        }
                        //exportExcelFile(response.data!!)
                    }
                }
                is ResponseResult.Error -> {
                    Log.d(
                        "GET_TRANSACTIONS_IN_EXCEL_ERROR",
                        "Network Call Failed With Exception: " + response.exception.message
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainNavController composable screen:

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
@Composable
fun MainNavController() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    var currentScreen by remember { mutableStateOf(Screens.SPLASH_SCREEN) }
    var forceBottomBarHide by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var topBarTitle by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var topBarSubTitle by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var excelExportPopup by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val viewModel: MainNavControllerViewModel = remember { getKoin().get() }
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ) { activityResult ->
        if (activityResult.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            activityResult.data?.data?.also { uri->
                try {
                    if(activityResult.data == null) Log.d("TEST_EW","intent was null")
                    if(activityResult.data!!.extras == null) Log.d("TEST_EW","extras was null")
                    val bytes = activityResult.data?.extras?.getByteArray("bytes")
                    if(bytes == null) Log.d("TEST_EW","bytes was null")
                    contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "w")?.use { parcelFileDescriptor ->
                        FileOutputStream(parcelFileDescriptor.fileDescriptor).use { fos->
                            Log.d("TEST_EW","byteArray =  ${bytes.contentToString()}")
                            fos.write(bytes)
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
            return@rememberLauncherForActivityResult
        }
    }
    ScreenBackground(screen = currentScreen)
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = NavigationGraphs.SPLASH_SCREEN.route
        ) {
            splashScreenNavigation(navController) { currentScreen = it }
            onBoardingNavigation(navController) { currentScreen = it }
            dashboardNavigation(
                navController,
                currentScreen,
                updateCurrentScreen = { currentScreen = it },
                setForceBottomBarHide = { forceBottomBarHide = it },
                updateTopBarTitle = { title ->
                    topBarTitle = title
                })
            loginNavigation(navController) { currentScreen = it }
            registrationNavigation(navController) { currentScreen = it }
            activationNavigation(navController) { currentScreen = it }
            contactNavigation(navController) { currentScreen = it }
            settingsNavigation(navController) { currentScreen = it }
            miscScreensNavigation(navController) { currentScreen = it }
            requestNavigation(navController) { currentScreen = it }
            paymentsNavigation(
                navController,
                updateCurrentScreen = { currentScreen = it },
                setForceBottomBarHide = { forceBottomBarHide = it },
                updateTopBarSubtitle = { topBarSubTitle = it }
            )
            topUpNavigation(
                navController,
                updateCurrentScreen = { currentScreen = it },
                updateTopBarTitle = { title ->
                    topBarTitle = title
                })
        }
        if (currentScreen.topBarVisibility) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter)) {
                TopBar(
                    title = topBarTitle,
                    notificationBell = currentScreen.topBarNotifications,
                    backNavigationArrow = currentScreen.topBarNavigation,
                    subtitle = currentScreen.topBarSubtitle,
                    downloadButton = currentScreen.topBarDownloadButton,
                    subtitleValue = topBarSubTitle,
                    openExcelExportModal = { excelExportPopup = true }
                )
            }
        }

        if (currentScreen.bottomBarVisibility && !forceBottomBarHide) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter)) {
                MyBottomNavigationBar(navController, currentScreen)
            }
        }

        if (excelExportPopup) {
            ExcelExportPopup(excelExportPopup, hideExportPopup = {
                excelExportPopup = false
            }, setForceBottomBarHide = {
                forceBottomBarHide = it
            }
            ) {
                viewModel.exportTransactionsInExcel(context) { fileName, byteArray ->
                    excelExportPopup = false
                    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
                        Log.d("TEST_EW","byte array = ${byteArray.contentToString()}")
                        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                        type = "application/xlsx"
                        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, fileName)
                        putExtra("bytes",byteArray)
                    }
                    val bytes = intent.getByteArrayExtra("bytes")
                    if(bytes == null) Log.d("TEST_EW","bytes was null")
                    launcher.launch(intent)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `putExtra("bytes",byteArray)` That does not make any sense. What is it that you try to do? The content of the byte array will not be used by ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT. And is not available in on activity result as you get a different intent there.

Comment: @blackapps Oh I thought it was passing the same intent. I want to pass that byteArray into the `val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ) {..}` block in order to be able to write it into the file that I just created. I couldn't find this exact case in the docs when it comes to jetpack compose. Do you know what the suggested way of doing this is?

Comment: ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT gives you an uri. You can open an output stream for that uri and write your data to that stream.

Comment: @blackapps That is what I am doing, but I want to pass that byte Array to the Uri block which I get from my view Model through the callback that you see.

Comment: I can not follow your code. There is so much irrelevant code. Please clean up.

Comment: @blackapps I'm sorry, but it is very easy to filter out the few UI-related lines and the rest of the code is pretty straightforward IMO (especially with me having described the flow). Usually people need the rest of the class in order to help them debug, so I'm not planning on removing it. If you don't have the time for it, I completely understand!

Answer (score 1):

You are adding `ByteArray` to `Intent` extras using `putExtra`

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
                ...
                putExtra("bytes",byteArray) //here
            }
```

But, you are retrieving it as `bundle` using `val bytes = intent.getBundleExtra("bytes")`, as it's not a bundle it's returning `null`.

Use `getByteArrayExtra` to get the `ByteArray`

```
val bytes = intent.getByteArrayExtra("bytes")
```

Comment: sorry I was testing this as an alternative. The actual code uses your solution but the problem remains. I'll update that part sorry about that

Comment: Debug putting a breakpoint on `putExtra("bytes",byteArray)`, check `byteArray` is null or not.

Comment: `byteArray` is not null during that. I've confirmed this as I mentioned in my post. It looks like the issue is that a different intent is passed to the launcher callback as @blackapps mentioned in the comments.